# Meteor custom domain with own certification

Tags: meteor

When I deploy my app likes this:

```
$ mrt deploy owndomain.com
```

https://owndomain.com in web browser shows certification warning because that certification's common name is "*.meteor.com".

Is there anyway to fix it or replace certification with own certification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use your own certificates with meteor deploy hosting, at least not yet. They have a wildcard SSL cert that matches to '*.meteor.com'.

You would need to host it yourself to be able to use your own, or use a `.meteor.com` domain.

If you dont have a proxy for this that supports websockets you could use: https://github.com/Tarangp/Meteor-SSL-proxy